# Acessing Spark cluster from virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, virtualbox, nat

I am setting up a Apache Spark cluster on Ubuntu machines on my local network and everything went with no problems.

Now, I am trying to add more nodes to my cluster but these are Ubuntu VMs running on windows machines.

I cannot connect my VMs to the network using the bridge connection since the network does not allow it.

Assuming my master is at 10.40.11.43, my host at 10.40.11.90 and my VM at 10.2.0.15 in the NAT network, this is what happens:

on my VM, I run start-slave.sh spark://10.40.11.43:7077 and it creates the worker, and it successfully reaches the master.
on my master, the new worker is detected and the master tries to connect back to the worker at 10.2.0.15:1234(example port) but it cant, so it rejects the worker when the connection timeouts.

I don't fully understand what is going on here, but in my opinion the master is trying to reach some inaccessible place since it has to go to my host first and not to the VM's NAT network address.

Comment: I would add separate [Internal networking interfaces](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal) and use these to connect VMs.

Comment: @zero323 But how can I can access the network where the cluster is from an internal network ? isn't the internal network composed only by my guests and my host ?

Comment: No, internal network connects all guests and connection between these can be handled using built DHCP server. I haven't used VirtualBox in a while but generally speaking is not very hard to configure.